# can't join String[] because it's stored in an object

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and I'm running into difficulty with something simple. I create a vector like the below, where the third element is an array of Strings, not a String itself.

```
this.myvec = new Vector();
myvec.add("a");
myvec.add("b");
myvec.add(new String[]{
            "c",
            "d",
            "e",
            "f");
```

Later I want to iterate over this, but because some elements are Strings and some are String arrays, I have to do it like this. But I also want to log it, so I have a condition based on the type to send to different log statements.

However in the case of the array, I want to join it as you can see below.

```
for (Object myobj : myvec) {
    if (myobj.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
        log.info("My object is " + myobj);
    }
    else {
        log.info("My object is " + String.join(",", myobj));
    }
```

The second log statement doesn't compile because you can't have an Object be the second argument to String.join. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Read about casting at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html (also, `Vector` is best left alone: use `ArrayList` instead)

Comment: `Vector` is a super old class, even its own Javadoc states you should use regular `List` implementations instead, `ArrayList` for example. Please don't use **raw types**, always specify the generic type to use like `Vector<...>`. Even if you don't plan to restrict types, use `Vector<Object>` at least. As the element is only known to be `Object` at this point you need to **cast** it to `String[]` (you can check with `instanceof` before). Or don't mix types in collections, which is probably the best advice.

Comment: Instead you may create a common super class like `TextContainer` which can hold arbitrary many `String` elements, internally realized as `ArrayList` or also as `String` only wrapper in case of only one element. Then use this `TextContainer` as common class instead. It may then implement `Iterable<E extends CharSequence>` which makes using `String#join` possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to have mixed types in your Vector you can do it this way, using the `instanceof` keyword:

```
Vector<Object> myvec = new Vector<>();
myvec.add("a");
myvec.add("b");
myvec.add(new String[] {"c", "d", "e", "f"});
myvec.add(1); // Added to test the Unknow type object

for (Object myobj : myvec) {
  String myobjAsString = "Unknown"; // default

  if (myobj instanceof String) {
    myobjAsString = (String)myobj;
  } else if (myobj instanceof String[]) {
    String[] myarray = (String[])myobj;
    myobjAsString = String.join(",", myarray);
  }

  System.out.println("My object is " + myobjAsString);
}
```

Prints out:

```
My object is a
My object is b
My object is c,d,e,f
My object is Unknown
```

Side notes:

- Declare your Vector as a Vector of Objects: `Vector<Object>`. It is a Generic class. See [Vector Api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) and [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)
- Vector is only preferred in very specific cases (so specific that I can't think of one), I don't think you should be bothered with that at your level, you might prefer to use `ArrayLists<T>` in most if not all cases. See [Vector Vs ArrayList](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/difference-between-arraylist-and-vector-in-java/)
- To use an ArrayList instead of a Vector, simply declare:

  ```
  List<Object> myvec = new ArrayList<>();
  ```

  The rest of the code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  log.info("My object is " + String.join(",", (String[])myobj));
```

Comment: The problem is that `myobj` is only known to be of type `Object` at this point. Cast would be necessary before methods like this can be used.